# gtk/glade event handler that recursively fires after a set period of time (C)

Tags: c, unix, gtk, glade

I am using glade and need a way of a window after a set period of time, let's say one second. I have code that calculates the runtime and I can use that to ascertain exactly when a second has past.

I'm struggling to find a good way to integrate it into gtk. I can't use any of the regular event handlers as they rely on some degree of interaction. But this program relies on reading from various text files which are being constantly altered while the program is running.

Can anybody point me in the right direction or offer a solution?

Comment: `g_timeout_add()`. You can also integrate the file reading into the event loop and get events when they change; look up GIO (part of GLib, which GTK+ uses).

Comment: Or use `GFileMonitor` to emit events when your text files change.